# How to predict the player using random forest ML

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have to predict the winner of the Australian Open 2020. My dataset has these features: Location / Tournament / Date / Series / Court / Surface / Round / Winner / Loser etc.

I trained my model using just these features 'Victory','Series','Court','Surface','WinRank','LoseRank','WPts','LPts','Wsets','Lsets','Weather' and I have a 0.93 accuracy but now I have to predict the name of the winner and I don't have any idea how to do it based on the model that I trained.

Example:  If I have Dimitrov G. vs Simion G using random forest the model has to give me one of them as the winner of the match.

I transformed the names of the players in dummy variables but after that, I don't know what to do?

Can anyone give me just an idea of how could I predict the winner? so I can create a Tournament, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address such a problem, I would suggest creation of a custom target variable. 
Firstly, the transformation of names of players into dummy variables seems reasonable (Just make sure, the unique player is identified with the same first and last name combinations thereby, avoiding duplications and thus, having the correct dummy code for the player name).

Now, to create the target variable "wins" -

1. Use the two player names - P1, P2 of the match as input features for your model.
2. Define the "wins" as 1 if P1 wins and 0 if P2 wins.
3. Run your model with this set up.
4. When you want to create a tournament and predict the winner, the inputs will be your 2 players and other match features. If, "wins" is close to 1, it means your P1 wins and output that player name.

Comment: I create the victory feature as the target variable where I set it to 1 if player 1 won and vice-versa but now this is the part where I don't understand how to do it. I run the model the input is the accuracy: 0.93, but you tell me to give to the model the second player and to see it is close to 1, how I can do this? 
RanFo_algo=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1200, min_samples_split=5,min_samples_leaf= 2, 
 max_features='sqrt',max_depth=10,bootstrap=False)
 RanFo_algo.fit(X_train,y_train)
 accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=RanFo_algo.predict(X_test))
 print(accuracy)

Comment: X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test are based on the features above : 'Victory','Series','Court','Surface','WinRank','LoseRank','WPts','LPts','Wsets','Lsets','Weather', i didn't use the player 1 and player 2 but i can include them no problem then i don't know what to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By adding player 1 and player 2 names as features, you will be making the model to learn from - 
1. match data - meaning, each row is a match data record containing information about the 2 players, loserank, series, lpts etc...

2. By defining the target as 1 when P1 wins.

This is forcing the model to understand that the target is 1, when P1 has higher probability of winning

Comment: And to the question - "tell me to give to the model the second player and to see it is close to 1, how I can do this?" - this is handled automatically by our assumption that if the probability is close to 1, P1 wins and if it is close to 0, it means P2 wins. So, there is no need for something additional other than including P2 as input and defining the target as explained previously

Comment: Thank you I will try to do that.